# STATS, Expected value of random walk

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to settle a dispute with the following question:

A drunk is walking home, he starts at position 0, each step he takes could either be 1 unit to the right$(-1)$, with the probability $p$ or 1 unit to the left$(+1)$, with the probability $1 - p$

NOTE: Each step the drunk takes is independent of any previous

How far left or right do you expect his position to be after n steps? Let X be his position after n steps

**Now I claimed** that this can be seen as a binomial distribution and therefore $E[X] = np$

**But my friend said** that it is not a distribution at all, but a distance formula, so he claimed: let $a_1 =$ acceleration left and $a_2 =$ acceleration right, $E[X] = a_1n - a_2n$

If you guys have any input on this it would be much appreciated, thankyou for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not binomial; what you've counted is the expected number of steps to the right.  Here's a hint: if you call $Y_i$ the position changed due to the $i$th step, then you have $$X = Y_1 + \cdots + Y_n.$$

What is the expected value of each $Y_i$?  What does this tell you about $E[X]$?